# Programmatically getting Apache Camel components operations, parameters, options decriptions

Tags: apache-camel

Is there a way to get any Apache Camel component "metadata" using Java code, like the list of options and other parameters and their types? I think some automatic help builder was mentioned somewhere that might be of use for this task without using reflection.
A way to get the registered components of all types (including data formats and languages) with java code is also sought. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah take a look at the `camel-catalog` JAR which includes all such details. This JAR is what the tooling uses such as some of the Maven tooling itself, or IDE plugs for IntelliJ or Eclipse etc. The JAR has both Java API and metadata files embedded in the JAR you can load.

At runtime you can also access this catalog via `RuntimeCamelCatalog` which you can access via `CamelContext`. The runtime catalog is a little bit more limited than `CamelCatalog` as it has a *view* of what actually is available at runtime in the current Camel application.

Also I cover this in my book Camel in Action 2nd edition where there is a full chapter devoted on Camel tooling and how to build custom tooling etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've found so far

http://camel.apache.org/componentconfiguration.html